# Determine greatest common divisor, possibly involving the euc. algorithm

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Let $m,n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n= 2k-1$ ($n$ is odd). Find $(2^m +1, 2^n -1)$, where by $(a,b)$ we mean the greatest common divisor of $a,b$.

Attempt:
Let $(2^m +1, 2^n -1)=:d$, then  $$d\mid (2^m+1)\land d\mid (2^n -1)\Rightarrow d\mid (2^m + 2^n)\Leftrightarrow d\mid (2^m+2^{2k-1})$$
If $m\geq 2k-1$, that is $m=2k-1+r, r\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, then $d\mid 2^{2k-1}(2^r+1)$ and I'm stuck. What should I do from here? How would $n$ being odd help the case?

Was told to use the euclidean algorithm here, but I don't understand what was meant by that.

References to similar problems would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the general formula:
1$$\gcd(2^a-1,2^b-1)=2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1 \tag 1$$
You can apply $(1)$ for $(a,b)=(2m,n)$ and $(a,b)=(m,n)$ you will obtain:

$$\begin{align}\gcd(2^{2m}-1,2^n-1)&=2^{\gcd(2m,n)}-1=2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1=d \tag 2 \\
\gcd(2^{m}-1,2^n-1&)=2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1=d `\tag3\end{align}$$

And from here you can see if $x=2^m-1,y=2^m+1$ and $z=2^n-1$ you have:
$$\gcd(xy,z)=\gcd(x,z)=d $$

You can conclude that $\gcd(y,z)=1 $

Comment: where did the $(a,b) = (2m,n)$ come from?

Comment: I mean that you can take $a=2m$ and $b=n$ in the formula $(1)$

Comment: Yes, I understand that part, but I don't understand how you came up with this substitution and furthermore $$(a,b)=(2m,n)\Rightarrow (a,b)=(m,n)$$?

Comment: I mean that you can take $a=2m$ and $b=n$ in the formula (1) and obtain (2). And take $a=m$ and $b=n$ in the formula (1) and obtain (3). (There is no implication between the two of them )

Comment: After fiddling around with algebra, I found answers to all of what you pointed out. Thank you for your time.